# Prepared statements (LIKE, ORDER BY)

Tags: sql-injection, python

I'm trying to fix up SQL request by using prepared statements but looks like it works in some different way with the `LIKE` operator, I have the following request:

```
db.execute("SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY created_at %s"
                              % (search_title, order_by))
```

I tried to rebuild it into the prepared statement like:

```
pattern = "%%" + search_title + "%%"
articles = db.execute("SELECT * FROM article WHERE title LIKE (pattern = %s) ORDER BY created_at (order_by = %s)", [pattern, order_by])
```

but it breaks the query.

I understand that usually, the pattern for the prepared statement in Python is like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE username = %s'", (username, ));
```

But could anyone please explain to me how to re-build more complex and difficult SQL requests because all examples that I googled were really simple?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "breaks the query"? The `ORDER BY` being dynamic is a problem -- you'll need to build a new prepared statement for each possible value, or just continue to use string concatenation but validate the value (which shouldn't be hard, since the set of possible table names is fixed). The LIKE pattern being dynamic (so long as you append and prepend the wildcards in Python) shouldn't be a problem at all -- neither your database engine nor the DB-API should have any objection to it.

Comment: ...so really, the `LIKE` and `ORDER BY` cases are two separate questions, with two separate answers, and they shouldn't be asked together.